# how to an alertdialog in a simple class?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I created an alertbox in a simple class but I don't know what is the problem. My code is given below. When I run my activity and I would like to run my alertdialog the application crash.

```
private class ApplicationLauncher implements
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView parent, View v,
                final int position, long id) {
            // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext());
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle("TestsAuthen");
            builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ApplicationInfo app = (ApplicationInfo) parent
                                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
                            startActivity(app.intent);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

            // //////////////////
        }
    }
```

Comment: crash! post the stack trace

Comment: post the logcat error report

Comment: Using getApplicationContext like that is not good idea

Comment: what to put as a context

Comment: add a `constructor` to this class which take `Context` as parameter, and when you instantiate this class, pass the Activity context, and use that context in this class.

Comment: Create a Field `Context context;` and give it as a `context=this`

Comment: i know that it is a problem of context. sory for the trace i have a problem with my eclipse i cont get the log. if you want i can make an adb logcat.

Comment: trace or logcat, it will help, so post it too !

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to build an alertDialog with the `getApplicationContext().`
You need to pass it the activities context.

try

```
private class ApplicationLauncher implements
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        Context context;

        public ApplicationLauncher(Context context){
          this.context = context;
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView parent, View v,
                final int position, long id) {
            // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                   context);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle("TestsAuthen");
            builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ApplicationInfo app = (ApplicationInfo) parent
                                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
                            startActivity(app.intent);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

            // //////////////////
        }
    }
```

Now simply pass your context `this` to the constructor like

```
  new ApplicationLauncher(this);
```

Comment: I have done some things else I creat an public static varaible with the type Activity. in my MAin Activity and then i used it as a context

Comment: and it works. public static Activity fa; then fa = this in the oncreat method of my main activity.

Comment: Did you even try this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to you class, which initialises the local context;

```
public class ApplicationLauncher implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private Context context;

public ApplicationLauncher(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
...

}
```

instantiate this class in your activity as;

```
 ApplicationLauncher al = new ApplicationLauncher( this );
```